# Tarea Azure Copy File no funciona como se espera en Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, vsts, yaml, devops

En Azure DevOps tengo un repositorio GIT el cual tiene una serie de archivos y carpetas dentro:

```
 - pipelines
       - pipeline1
       - pipeline2
       - pipelineN

 - readme.MD

 - archivo.xlsx
```

Mi intención es subir únicamente el archivo .xlsx al Container de un Azure Storage Account. Para ello utilizo el campo `Contents` dentro de la tarea `Azure Copy File`, os enseño la tarea del YAML:

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      !.git/**/*
      !pipelines/*
      !readme.MD
      *.xlsx
    azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
    Destination: 'mydestination'
    storage: 'mystorage'
    ContainerName: 'mycontainer'
```

En el campo `contents` intento recoger mera y únicamente el archivo .xlsx para realizar la carga en el StorageAccount de solo este archivo, pero para mi sorpresa veo que está cargando todos los archivos que aparecen en la rama de GIT y no sólo el deseado.

Bajo mi punto de vista el error está claramente en el campo `contents`, por lo que entiendo de la documentación:

```
!.git/**/*    -> Exclusión de carpeta GIT y todos sus contenidos y subcontenidos.
!pipelines/*  -> Exclusión de la carpeta pipelines y sus contenidos.
!readme.MD    -> Exclusión del archivo readme.MD
*.xlsx        -> Agrego todos los archivos en la raíz que tengan extensión xlsx
```

Cabe destacar que he utilizado distintas versiones de la tarea `AzureFileCopy` y en todas he obtenido el mismo resultado.

¿Qué estoy realizando mal? ¿Se trata de la declaración de los contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la documentación oficial no existe el input `Contents` para este task, pruebe lo siguiente

```
SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\archivo.xlsx'
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta (veo que era mucho más fácil de como lo estaba planteando), y disculpa si por desconocimiento realizo preguntas básicas, estoy empezando con el mundo de DevOps. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Por nada me alegro que resolviera el problema